# Is there a way to see how many lines of code were written by an author in Git by directory?

Tags: git, bash, shell

Is there a way to see how many *lines of code* were written by an author in Git by directory? So, not everything within the git repo, just one specific subfolder of the git project in a format like shortlog?

Comment: You want a count of lines in the current revision that were last touched by each author?

Answer (score 4):

If you want a count of current code lines by author I believe the following will do what you want. (There may be better ways but this was the first thing I thought of.)

```
{ for file in *; do git annotate --line-porcelain "$file" 2>/dev/null; done; } | awk '$1 == "author" {authors[$2]++; } END {for (author in authors) {print author ": " authors[author]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call:

```
git log --author="<author name>" --pretty=tformat: --numstat app/src
```